# Retrieve subject name with maximum mark

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I had a problem while trying to retrieve the subject name with the maximum mark. I'm using SQL Server 2008.

I had two tables as following:

Subject table:

```
create table [Subject]
(
    SubID int identity(1,1) primary key,

    SubName nvarchar(30) not null,

    SubCredit tinyint not null constraint Default_value_Subect default(1) constraint Check_value_Subject check(SubCredit>=1),

    SubStatus bit constraint default_value_SubStatus default(1)
)
```

Mark table:

```
create table Marks
(
    MarkID int identity(1,1) primary key,

    SubID int foreign key references [Subject](SubID),

    StudentID int foreign key references Students(StudentID),

    Mark float constraint Check_value_Mark check(Mark>=0 and Mark <=100) constraint Default_value_Mark Default(0),

    ExamTime tinyint constraint Default_value_Examtime default(1)
)
```

I used this SQL statement to retrieve the SubID with maximum mark:

```
select Marks.SubID, MAX(Marks.Mark) as diem 
from Marks 
group by Marks.SubID
```

but I wanted to retrieve the `SubName` value instead of `SubID`.
How can I do? Please show me how!
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a method just using `join` and `order by`:

```
select top 1 s.*
from subject s join
     mark m
     on s.subid = m.subid
order by m.mark desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, find the subject ID with the max mark, then use that ID to find the subject data:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Subject]
WHERE SubID =
(    -- Max Mark
     SELECT TOP 1 
     SubID
     FROM Marks
     ORDER BY Mark DESC
)
```